# How to add a new ImageView to ConstraintLayout in AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-studio

in my app the user presses a button to send their answer to a server, using asynctask, and I show an image depending on their answer.

Here's the code in onPostExecute() :

```
ConstraintLayout root = findViewById(R.id.root);
ImageView img = new ImageView(PlayActivity.this);
img.setId(R.id.answerImage);
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.correct_answer);
img.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
ConstraintSet cs = new ConstraintSet();
cs.connect(img.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.answerButton, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 32);
cs.applyTo(root);
img.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
root.addView(img, params);
try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch(InterruptedException e) {
    Log.e("exception", e.getMessage());
}
root.removeView(img);
```

The id I used in setId is defined in ids.xml file.

However the image simply isn't showing.
I tried this code without ConstraintSet / setting width and height to 100 in LayoutParams / using setImageDrawable instead of setImageResource. Nothing worked.

I am using the "Check" clip art in android studio as a drawable if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Using addView() DOES work. I used Thread.sleep() to show the image for two seconds before removing it with removeView(), but apparently removeView() is executed immediately.